# Do secondary stars in binary systems affect how the habitable zone is calculated or they can be calculated separately?

Tags: habitable-zone

I was taking a look at this tool to calculate habitable zones: [Calculation of habitable zones](https://depts.washington.edu/naivpl/sites/default/files/hz.shtml) which is pretty simple: you need to input Teff in Kelvins and Stellar Luminosity in solar units. Then I was wondering if this calculation is affected when you have binary systems and the tool just doesn't work anymore, or each habitable zone can be calculated separately. Do the effects of both stars add up and alter the calculation?

Comment: It's complicated. There's some relevant info at https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/385/16685

Comment: From that link everything seems to point that they affect the calculation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could there be Earth-like planets in binary or trinary systems?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/385/could-there-be-earth-like-planets-in-binary-or-trinary-systems)

Comment: The first link does, the link posted by PM 2Ring, specifically this part "their combined energy extends the habitable region farther away than would exist around a single star."